# Passing array from controller to view without using model

Tags: codeigniter-3

I have written code for accessing the array from the controller to view. but i am not able to access data on view.
codes are given below.

```
<?php
public function Student(){
   $exam_no_students = array();
   $exam_centers['no_of_centers']= $this->DB1->count_centers();
   $exam_centers1= $this->DB1->count_centers();
   foreach ($exam_centers1 as $center_code => $center_details){
      $center_code = array('center_id' =>$center_details->center_id);
      $center_table='exam_center';
      $center_full_details =$this->DB1->getArrayWhereResult($center_table,$center_code);
      foreach ($center_full_details as $full => $full_de) {
           $fullstudent = array('center_f_id' =>$full_de->center_id,
                     'center_f_name' =>$full_de->exam_center,
                     'center_f_addres' =>$full_de->exam_center_address ,
                     'center_f_city' =>$full_de->village ,
                     'center_f_count' =>$center_details->count);
                      }
          array_push($exam_no_students, $fullstudent);                  
    }
   }
}

$abcd['assignment']=$exam_no_students;                      
$this->load->view('dissa');
$this->load->view('dissa',$abcd);
```

I am not able to access variable **assignment** at the view.

> Message: Trying to get property of non-object please give me suggestion.

Thanks.

Comment: Please check whether `$exam_no_students` has data. Try `print_r` to make sure it is not empty.

Comment: Can you please provide, how you are rendering the data in the view. It will be more specific

Comment: Yes $exam_no_students has data

Comment: I can help you only if you post the rest of the code snippets.

Comment: The above problem Has been solved. i was using foreach and access in  $staff_list->id that manner, that gives error. instead of $staff_list->id it will be   $staff_list['id'].Thanks for support.

Comment: Cool. Happy Coding